# GVim Ctrl-W source code

Tags: vim

Where can I find the source code for C-W operation (delete a word in insert mode) of GVim?
I tried to search in the Vim repository http://vim.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/vim/vim7/ but I am not able to find it there. 
I need the implementation in vimscript and not c++.

Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: May I ask what you want to do with this information? I'm too curious, I know. Anyway, this core feature is more than likely written in c++. Don't you think?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vim is written in C (not C++), and the code for the insert mode  command is therefore written in C, not Vimscript. If you look at line 1074 in [`src/edit.c`](http://fossies.org/unix/misc/vim-7.3.tar.gz/dox/edit_8c_source.html) you can see that the `ins_bs()` function is used:

```
case Ctrl_W:    /* delete word before the cursor */
    did_backspace = ins_bs(c, BACKSPACE_WORD, &inserted_space);
    auto_format(FALSE, TRUE);
    break;
```

You should probably just explain what you *really* want to do, though…

Answer (score 1):

[<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd>](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/index.html#CTRL-W) is not specific to gVim.

The code is in `edit()` in [`src/edit.c`](http://vim.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/vim/vim7/src/edit.c?revision=1889&view=markup).

Answer (score 0):

It's bound to be in there. It's all in there. That being said, it is probably not coded in Vimscript but in ... (C++ ?). Vimscript is Vim's internal scripting language, not the language most of Vim is written in.